# При разворачивании проекта на node.js на сервере выдаёт ошибку, связанную с node_modules/esbuild. Как её решить?

Tags: node.js, сервер, npm, build, node-modules

Пытаюсь загрузить свой проект на сервер, используя Putty (у меня ОС Windows).
На сервере есть требования к версии node. Изменила на своём ноутбуке и на сервере версии так, чтобы они совпадали, но всё равно при запуске команды npm i на сервере не устанавливается папка node_modules и появляются ошибки.
Работаю с сервером впервые, поэтому не знаю как решить эту проблему.
Версия node 16.20.2 (до этого были установлены версии повыше)
Версия npm 9.6.6
Может есть какие-нибудь предположения? Рассмотрю любые варианты.

Код ошибок:

```
[Irina@s61]:<~/domains/***/public_nodejs/tea>$ npm i
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /usr/home/Irina/domains/***/public_nodejs/tea/node_modules/esbuild
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node install.js
npm ERR! node:internal/errors:478
npm ERR!     ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
npm ERR!     ^
npm ERR!
npm ERR! <ref *1> Error: spawnSync /usr/home/Irina/domains/***/public_nodejs/tea/node_modules/esbuild/bin/esbuild EACCES
npm ERR!     at Object.spawnSync (node:internal/child_process:1119:20)
npm ERR!     at spawnSync (node:child_process:847:24)
npm ERR!     at Object.execFileSync (node:child_process:890:15)
npm ERR!     at validateBinaryVersion (/usr/home/Irina/domains/***/public_nodejs/tea/node_modules/esbuild/install.js:98:28)
npm ERR!     at /usr/home/Irina/domains/***/public_nodejs/tea/node_modules/esbuild/install.js:285:5 {
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'spawnSync /usr/home/Irina/domains/***/public_nodejs/tea/node_modules/esbuild/bin/esbuild',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/home/Irina/domains/***/public_nodejs/tea/node_modules/esbuild/bin/esbuild',
npm ERR!   spawnargs: [ '--version' ],
npm ERR!   error: [Circular *1],
npm ERR!   status: null,
npm ERR!   signal: null,
npm ERR!   output: null,
npm ERR!   pid: 0,
npm ERR!   stdout: null,
npm ERR!   stderr: null
npm ERR! }

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /home/Irina/.npm/_logs/2023-11-20T13_54_25_396Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: подскажите, как добавить код текстом, чтобы он не склеивался?

Comment: спасибо, Александр)

Comment: вы устанавливали библиотеки из под другого пользователя или от root-а?

Comment: @nörbörnën не от root. Чтобы войти на сервер, я должна вписывать свой логин.

Comment: а название каталога у вас реально 3 звездочки?

Comment: @nörbörnën нет, я его здесь замаскировала ***, там другое название.

Comment: прочитайте https://github.com/evanw/esbuild/issues/1711#issuecomment-1027554035 и комментарии после него. может быть это ваш случай (snap)?